# SELECT SUM with date variable, for prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, select, sum, prestashop

i'd like to have a result on PHP/MYSQL
I have a table ps_orders with price on total_paid

I need to ask total for all price in current date, i have dificult ti insert correct date. I'm stopping here, and do not works... thnaks

```
....

$date = date("Y-m-d");

$query = "SELECT SUM(total_paid) FROM ps_orders WHERE delivery_date = '%$date%'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Comment: What are the `%` characters doing there?

Comment: sorry, i must ask day date and i thik to use jolly character.

Comment: The only "jolly characters" that I know are usually to be found down at the pub from around 7pm.  Oh, and St Nicholas of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(total_paid) FROM ps_orders WHERE delivery_date = '$date'";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(total_paid) FROM ps_orders WHERE delivery_date LIKE '%$date%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on how your delivery_date field is setup as well as what you are using in your $date variable (time stamp vs just m-d-y), your query up to the where clause looks okay, but you could also try:

```
SELECT SUM(total_paid)
FROM ps_orders
WHERE delivery_date = $date;
```

if you are using a datetime field for delevery_date, you'll have to go more in depth and use a range:

```
SELECT SUM(total_paid)
FROM ps_orders
where (delivery_date > $date
and deliver_date < $date +interval 1 day)
```

This link should also help you out quite a bit when working with date: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following:

1. DATE function in mysql converts `2013-11-20 10:54:12` to `2013-11-20`, i.e. truncated a time in date

   $query = "SELECT SUM(total_paid) FROM ps_orders WHERE DATE(delivery_date) = '$date'";
2. or you use only one '%' after $date with using LIKE, so this value will be matched for dates like `2013-11-20 10:12:13` :

   $query = "SELECT SUM(total_paid) FROM ps_orders WHERE delivery_date like '$date%'";
3. or use string mysql function SUBSTRING

   $query = "SELECT SUM(total_paid) FROM ps_orders WHERE SUBSTRING(delivery_date1, 1, 10) = '$date'";
4. use datetime with time and BETWEEN mysql comparison operator:

   $query = "SELECT SUM(total_paid) FROM ps_orders WHERE delivery_date1 between '$date 00:00:00' and '$date 23:59:59'